# Unallocated space in empty flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, flash-memory

[image]

Hello, I am trying to recover unallocated space in my flash drive. I'm not quite sure how it got to this point. I have tried the following commands:

resize2fs

sudo resize2fs /dev/sdc1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 1011875 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

badblock

sudo resize2fs /dev/sdc1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 1011875 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

When I use Check in gparted, nothing happens.
How can I recover the space on my flashdrive? Sorry for the poor formatting, still learning...

Comment: little late for the answer but this video might be helpful https://youtu.be/MShpImlWVFM

Answer (score 1):

Before resizing your filesystem, you need to extend your partition.

One way to do that would be with fdisk. Say I have a 20G disk, with a 5G partition like this:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
> p
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
...
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048    40957    43005   5G 83 Linux
```

First, I'll delete my partition, then create one starting at the same sector, finishing at the end of my disk, using the same partition type.

```
Command (m for help): d       
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-41943039, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-41943039, default 41943039): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 20 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
...
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
```

If you're sure the partition starts at the same offset, then you may write your changes:

```
Command (m for help): w
```

Your OS may not be able to reload the partition table, at which point you could have to reboot. Or, with a removable media, just unplug/plug back in.

Then, you'll be able to use `resize2fs`.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your comment. 
When I try to delete the partition, it says the following:

No partition is defined yet!
Could not delete partition 1

Comment: Are you sure you opened the right device (`/dev/sdc`)? Listing partitions (with `p`) should confirm something exists. Does it?